# Define Primary Key, Hibernate Reverse Engeneering, Oracle Sequence

Tags: oracle, hibernate, netbeans, reverse-engineering

i would like to generate java classes using hibernate (Netbeans).
This seems not to be possible when the tables do not have a primary key.

I have no access to the database, i just found out, that they used sequences instead of primary keys.

```
create sequence SEQ_ANY
minvalue 0
maxvalue 99999999999999999999
start with 0
increment by 1000
cache 20;
```

So my Question is now, can i edit hibernate.hbm or hibernate.cfg.xml or any other file to tell hibernate which class contains a primary key? 
f.e.

```
<table name="myTable">
<useThisFieldAsPrimaryKey name="uniqueSequenz"/>
</table>
```

Thank you!

Comment: A sequence is an object for generating a sequence of numbers, which can then be used to populate a primary key column, so don't confuse primary keys and sequences in Oracle -- they are related but not equivalents

Comment: Sounds like an example of "Treasure Of The Sierra Madre design" - "Keys?  We ain't got no keys.  We don' need no keys!  I don't have to show you any steekeeng keys!!".  <sigh>  Those that cannot learn from history are doomed to be it.

Comment: so true @BobJarvis. But that does not answer my question :)

Answer (score 0):

A sequence is an objects to provide you with unique values for a primary may. Thus your table probably has a primary key which consists of a single column.

Then every table has a primary key (in the worst case all columns together form the primary key - which normally would be a bad database design). A primary key can have more than one column.

Hibernate likes primary keys which are made of a single column. Nevertheless you can define composite keys made of more than one column in Hibernate.

You need the schema of your table. If not you are stuck.

Comment: Sorry for the late answer. I allready know what you wrote, my problem is, that i cannot access the database (so i cannot change any table) and i know that the used sequences instead of primary keys. That design really s**ks.
My Question is only, can i tell the generating process of hibernate: "USE THAT COLUMN XYZ AS PK?" Or do i have to write my own classes instead of letting generate them?
Thank you!

Comment: @djnose - I suspect you're going to have to write your own classes.